# Pandas Multiindex versus dictionary of Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A dataframe with a multiindex can be considered a nested structure, with (for the sake of example) two levels - the first level being a single index, with each index pointing to a dataframe. The case of a dataframe without multiindex is a special case of a dataframe with multiindex, where the dataframe being pointed to is simply one row (a tuple, in mathematical terms).

From this high level perspective, a dataframe with multiindex seems to be equivalent to a dictionary whose key value pairs are indices and dataframes respectively. However, this is a superficial and high level view that doesn't take actual implementation or use cases into account.

That being said, is there a difference between these two methods? Is one preferred to another? My assumption is multiindices are preferred as they feel "cleaner" and help Pandas be "self contained", however at the same time, multiindices often feel like a pain to work with.

Comment: MultiIndex is not just more contained but allow for further operations, for example, slicing at first index level with [`.xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html), or `unstack/pivot`. This is pretty much like why you have a dataframe but not a dictionary of series. Of course this is just in general, YMMV depending on the use case.

Comment: @QuangHoang that makes sense, re: dictionary of series, Pandas column operations are fast, and one can't access columns with dictionaries without some annoying list comprehension, so I assume that the same logic generalizes to multiindices.